# Append a string in the log file (.txt) created using robocopy

Tags: command-line, robocopy

Currently with this command:

> robocopy Y:\source X:\target\Test /log:Y:\source\dem.txt /s /njh /njs /nc /np /ns /tee

I am able to create a log file (dem.txt) which contains the name of the files copied and also name their source folder. However, I want my log file to display something like

> NameOfFile has been successfully copied from PathOfSource to PathOfTarget

Note: My Source Folder has sub-folders inside which assets are stored. few assets are in root folder as well

Is there a way in which I can append this text in my log file?

Answer (score 0):

Based from this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23274387/batch-file-prompt-for-source-destination-with-robocopy you can set the variables in a .bat file using SET and then ECHO after the copying is done.

To add the text, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139157/append-text-with-bat

Comment: This doesn't answer my question as it is not modifying/adding any text to the log file as desired by me

Comment: @YashSaraiya added more info on the ECHO

Comment: I cannot make it work.... Is there a way in which we can do this using only robocopy (no batch files and scripts) ?

Comment: @YashSaraiya No. There is no way to customise Robocopy log files other than by using the flags you have already discovered. Any other customisation requires using a different approach (some form of scripting). In that case you might as well do the whole thing in custom script and not use robocopy at all!